# How deep can I perform the Firestore Queries

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am just getting started with Firestore. For performing Queries, Firestore comes recommended, unlike Realtime Database. Can someone clarify me on how deep I can go with using queries in Firestore?

For illustration, let us take a list of School Students. Each Document contains information about **Name, Age, Gender, City, Language, Specialization**. So can I perform a compound query like the following?

```
Query studentList = db.collection("students")
                      .whereEqualTo("age", 12)
                      .whereEqualTo("gender", "female")
                      .whereEqualTo("city", "paris")
                      .whereEqualTo("language", "french")
                      .whereEqualTo("specialization", "maths");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can apply multiple conditions to a query.  Each condition is logically AND'd with each other.  So, the query you're showing now effectively asks for documents in the `students` collection where age=12 AND gender=female AND city=paris AND language=french AND specialization=maths.

Please [consult the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to understand better how Firestore queries work.